# How to copy mesh to new files with Python?

Tags: scripting, data-blocks

I have a blend file with hundreds of mesh objects as part of a kit bash pack.

I want to copy each mesh to its own file and turn those files into KPacks for Kit Ops addon.

To export each mesh into a new file I tried to use this code:

```
import bpy

base_path = "c:\\temp\\"

for idx, obj in enumerate(bpy.data.objects):
    bpy.data.libraries.write(f'{base_path}obj_{idx}.blend', {obj}, fake_user=True)
```

The problem is that in the files created by the script, only the data blocks are copied, there are no meshes created.

How can I copy each mesh to a new file? It would be very tedious to do that manually for hundreds of files.

Comment: Could simply `libraries.write(fp, use_fake_user=True)` to stop orphans. Seems over kill to add a  collection for a one object file.  If using collections would add multiple objects to collection then write collection to lib.

Comment: @batFINGER You're right, that does stop the data from being orphaned. I was mistaken though, I don't need to copy just the data, but actual mesh. I need to have the objects visible and editable. Seems that just copying the data block is not enough, I have to find a way to copy the entire mesh to a new file. I updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: Can't find the link, sure this has been asked before. Will notice on opening a library file that there is no scene.  In later versions a dummy scene is created, to which it is simply a matter of linking objects, or using script as answered below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found how to do it. The code I had was half the solution.

After creating a new file, executing the following script adds the mesh to a collection in the scene as I needed. It assumes there's no collection and only one data block in the blend file.

*add_object.py*

```
import bpy

collection = bpy.data.collections.new("Collection 1")
bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(collection)
collection.objects.link(bpy.data.objects[0])
bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(filepath=bpy.data.filepath)
```

To execute the script, I executed this in a loop:

```
blender.exe  <path_to_new_blend_file> --background --python add_object.py
```